# Resharper template quick menu showing more entries than configured

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates, resharper

Just started using Resharper file templates, but the quick list has more menu entries than I would expected. Please see the following screenshot.

Left side shows what I have configured for the quicklist, right side shows the outcome that includes more than the configured entry `My template`.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

on the right of your screenshot there are shown all templates as "All Applicable File Templates" menu is opened. To open quick list please right click on the project name, then select Add | New from Template.

[image: New from Template]